# How to pass custom parameters to screen flow in public community?

Tags: community, visual-workflow, url, parameters, screen-flow

Thanks for the help in advance.

I'm passing a URL in an email. The URL sends the user to a public community flow page where a screen flow starts. This all works.

I have a custom parameter in the URL I am trying to pass to the flow. This does not work.

When the community page is rendered, the parameter is set to null in the flow, even though the flow variable is in the URL. The URL works outside a community in normal Salesforce. This is NOT a recordId.

**Example URL with the flow variable and string example outside community (WORKING):**
https://DomainName.com/flow/FlowName?UniqueToken=1058352125

**Example URL with the flow variable and string example inside community (NOT WORKING):**
https://DomainName.force.com/CommunityName/s/flow/FlowName?UniqueToken=1058352125

I have scoured the internet and have found multiple questions posted about this with NO answers. I did find one blog post from 2017 explaining that you could call flows in a community using Flow URL but couldn't yet pass in parameters. I'm hoping it was implemented in the last 3 years or the blog post is incorrect...

Any help?

Comment: I'm dredging up this answer because this *was* working for me last week, but now the flow variable input won't save in the community. I try setting them, publishing the community, and visiting the flow page again, and it's not saved. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay. I figured this out. Once you have added the flow component to the community page, you need to click on it. In the input you should see your input parameters. In my situation, for the UniqueToken parameter, I needed to add {!UniqueToken}. Problem solved!

Comment: This is a hidden gem right here! Not sure if it'll work in a year or so but this is a great find!

Comment: hmm, it doesn't seem to be working anymore... Does it still work for you?

Comment: Still working as of August 2021. Implemented this using Public Community with a Screenflow! Lovely fix thanks